# Silverlight Listbox scrolling only works if i set the height

Tags: silverlight, scrollviewer

i have a listbox and i am trying to make the scrolling work without having to set the height, is this possible? Thanks. Below is the code. The scrolling does not work.

```
 <ListBox Name="EmployeeListBox" Background="Transparent"  
                             SelectionMode="Single"
                             ItemsSource="{Binding Employees, Mode=TwoWay}"  >
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate >
                <StackPanel>
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="120" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="140" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <TextBlock  Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" FontWeight="Bold" Text="Name:" />
                        <TextBlock x:Name="TextBlock1"  Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0"  
                                       Text="{Binding Name}" />
                    </Grid>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

and viewmodel:

```
 public class EmployeeDataContext
{
    public List<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
    public EmployeeDataContext()
    {
        GetEmployeeList();
    }
    private void GetEmployeeList()
    {
        Employees = new List<Employee>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i)
        {
            Employees.Add(new Employee() { Name = "Gema Arterton" });
        }
    }
}
public class Employee
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean, "without having to set the height"? I don't understand what that has to do with list box scrolling. Can you clarify?

Comment: for example if i set the height to 300 witch is less than the actual height when all the items are displayed then the scrolling works, if i dont set the height at all then the listbox just show all items in the browser screen all the way to the bottom and cut the rest of the items,I am gonna edit my question to include the full code of the list box that is not scrolling.

Comment: Still don't understand, even with the code sample. You can control whether the scrollbar is shown, hidden, auto, whatever, using <ListBox ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible">

Comment: Try putting the code in a page and you will see that the listbox just displays all items in the browser window ..no scrolling. I will add a viewmodel class you can hook into.

Comment: So, it's not wrapping the items to fit in the screen

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(sorry for my bad english)

It depends too on what control is the listbox inside. If your listbox is inside a Grid, it should take all the space of that grid - if it is inside a stackpanel it will use the least amount os space possible so you will have to use fixed height/width. Try this:

```
<UserControl...>
    <Grid>
      <ListBox HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">         
      </ListBox>
    </Grid>
</UserControl/>
```

The listbox should use all screen size and show vertical scrollbars if there is enough items.

Comment: Thanks Leo, I also noticed that I had my listbox inside a stackpanel and will never scroll and added a new test with a listbox straight inside a grid and scrolling started working, drove me nuts. :-)Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can set the height in scrollviewer

```
  <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" Height="480">
   <Grid Margin="0,0,0,50">  
   </Grid>
 </ScrollViewer>
```